# format a time difference automatically

Tags: r, date-format

Inside a function a need to convert some number, in general in range of 20 to 200, in to `difftime` and show via `format` as expected time needed to finish.

`as.difftime` has got a useful `units="auto"` so it will use "sec" say for 20 secs and "mins" for 60+ secs...

But it says also

```
> as.difftime(100, units="auto")
Error in as.difftime(100, units = "auto") : 
  need explicit units for numeric conversion
```

How can I avoid that?

EDIT: Current workaround

```
> (Sys.time()+100)-Sys.time()
Time difference of 1.666667 mins
```

Comment: I hate, hate, hate this "feature". I always need to use `difftime` explicitly or redefine `-.POSIXt` because of this. You could wrap your solution in a function: `as.difftime2 <- function(x) {o <- Sys.time();  o+x-o}`

Comment: Yeah me too... prob there's a reason, but I don't understand why the "auto" don't work for number. After all, the inner structure of `difftime` class is just a number ( plus units and class attribute of course)

Comment: you should save `Sys.time()` and then do that instead of computing it twice which could result in two different times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `lubridate` an alternative?

```
library(lubridate)
new_difftime(second = 20)
# Time difference of 20 secs

new_difftime(second = 60)
# Time difference of 1 mins

new_difftime(second = 240)
# Time difference of 4 mins

new_difftime(second = 1000000)
# Time difference of 11.57407 days

# new_difftime creates an object of same class as as.difftime does. 
class(as.difftime(20, units = "secs"))
# [1] "difftime"

class(new_difftime(second = 20))
# [1] "difftime"
```

It is also possible to specify input values of several units. E.g. from `?new_difftime`

```
new_difftime(second = 3, minute = 1.5, hour = 2, day = 6, week = 1)
# Time difference of 13.08441 days
```

Comment: really nice. Is there also a feature like: I have a difftime of 90 secs, and instead of showing 1.5 min it does 1'30" or similar?

Comment: Not in `new_difftime` itself. The function calls `make_difftime`, and you might have a look the code if you wish to customize the output. I don't have the time right now...

Comment: @nigmastar, but if `as.difftime` worked as expected, the format of the result would have been the same as for `new_difftime` - a difference of 90 secs is printed as 1.5 mins? Can't expect more of a solution...;)